# Buying bulk hops online

Tags: hops, buying, ingredients

I'm often tempted to buy my commonly used hop pellets online in bulk and storing them in my freezer.  A lot of the cheap bulk hops are from the previous year.  Assuming they are vacuum packed and frozen, is it safe to buy 2008 harvest hops or am I wasting my money?

Answer (score 2):

It's safe if stored properly. Their bittering power will diminish with time - software like ProMash will help you estimate their current alpha acid content.

Before using them just take a whiff to tell if they have developed any cheesy aromas. You can always make a giant batch of lambic if they get too old.

Comment: Are there sources online you would recommend that can be guaranteed to have stored the hops properly to begin with?

Comment: I have only used http://www.hopsdirect.com/ About to make another order.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you factor in the loss of alpha acid over time you should be fine.  A reputable supplier may even help you with the estimate.

I would also recommend that you plan to use them relatively quickly if you want to get the most out of them.  So think of your next 3-4 brew sessions and work with those hops.  I'd invest in a vacuum sealer yourself, to weigh and repackage these hops you get.